# Configure Apache to serialize access to a script?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, queue

Is there a way to configure Apache (any version) to serialize (and queue) requests to a specific set of scripts.  Not all requests of course, just ones to a small set of particular URIs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think there's any way this can be done with Apache itself other than setting maxclients to 1 and allowing only one server thread.

My approach to this problem would be a database or file where PHP stores information about wheather it's been executed from another client or not. If so, you could either wait or send an error message to the client.